# Why does `overflow: auto;` not cause an element to scroll even when its contents overflow?

Tags: html, css, scroll

Why does setting `overflow: auto;` on an element not cause it to scroll even when its contents overflow?

I have a two column layout with a fixed left column and a scrolling right column. The right column, is set to `overflow: auto;`, and it has a child `div.content`. If I set its minimum height taller than the window, the scroll bar will not appear. If I set the minimum height on its child, `div.content` the scroll bar appears.

Why is this? Why won't the scroll bar appear when the minimum height is set on `main`?

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gT8tq/1/

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <aside>
        <p>Fixed</p>
    </aside>
    <main>
        <section class="content">
            <p>Scroll</p>
        </section>
    </main>
</div>
```

Styles...

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.page-wrapper {
    bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
}
aside, main {
    bottom: 0; top: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}
aside {
    background-color: #eee;
    left: 0;
    width: 30%;
}
main {
    background-color: #ccc;
    left: 30%; right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    /* Here is the issue; uncommenting this breaks scrolling; Why? */
    /* min-height: 1000px; */
}
.content {
    min-height: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `overflow: auto`? There is no property called `scroll`.

Comment: div.content is not a div but a section: <section class="content"><p>I scroll...</p></section>, so section.content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set `min-height: 1000px` on your `main` element, what ends up happening is that its contents *no longer overflow it* because it is now 1000 pixels tall. Note that `min-height` takes precedence even though you anchored the `main` element to the page bounds using absolute positioning and `bottom: 0; top: 0`, simply because that results in the `main` element being less than 1000 pixels tall. What happens then is that the element remains anchored to the top according to its `top` coordinate and overflows downward, because it's *over-constrained* thanks to `min-height`; the details of all this are documented in sections [10.6.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-height) and [10.7](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-heights) of the spec.

Since overflow no longer occurs on the `main` element, it no longer needs to generate a scrollbar for its contents. The `main` element and its contents still overflow the page as I've described, but since you specified `overflow: hidden` on `html, body`, the page will refuse to generate a scrollbar for the `main` element. The end result, therefore, is that no scrollbar is generated at all.

If you force `main` to generate a vertical scrollbar even when no overflow occurs, by replacing `overflow: auto` with `overflow-y: scroll`, you'll see that [the scrollbar actually extends beyond the page bounds](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/gT8tq/5) such that you no longer see the bottom control(s) — this proves that by adding `min-height` you have in fact made the `main` element taller:

```
main {
    background-color: #ccc;
    left: 30%; right: 0;
    /* overflow: auto; */
    overflow-y: scroll;
    min-height: 1000px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your CSS,

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

It means that no matter how the height overflow the body element, the scroll bar will not appear.

Besides, `overflow: auto` in main element is required because actually the scroll bar belongs to the main element instead of the default body element.

```
main {
    background-color: #ccc;
    left: 30%; right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

If you do not want `overflow: hidden` in body element, you must set position:fixed to aside element.

Check it on http://jsfiddle.net/gT8tq/4/

Comment: What does setting `position: relative;` on `.content` achieve? And what does changing `aside` from `absolute`, in my case, to `fixed`, in your case, achieve?

Comment: I'm providing two method that can achieve more or less the same thing.

Comment: In your case, since the origin scroll bar is the 'main' element, 'aside' element will not be scrolled.

Comment: In my jsfiddle case, the origin of the scroll bar is 'body' element. Same effect but just showing you another way to achieve the visually same thing.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you set the behavior for a certain element, in this case `<main>`.
What should `<main>` do when it's contents are greater than the element itself?

In this case, you say it should create scrollbars in that case.
If you put overflow: auto; on the page-wrapper, it will do what you expect, because then you tell that div what to do when it's contents are overflowing.

Does that make sense or do you need more clarification?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. As it stands, `main` has `overflow: auto;` doesn't that tell it `if your contents overflow, show scrollbars` ?? Where does page wrapper come into this?

Comment: That is exactly what it means. If .content get's bigger than main is high, it will show scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use `position:relative;` for `.content` check this out:
http://jsfiddle.net/gT8tq/2/

Comment: I don't even have to do that. I could just remove min height from `main` and it works. What I am interested in is why this happens. Not the solution.

Comment: because `html blocks`'s `height` and `width` are `auto` by default, and in some case `blocks` could fill their container area without any code. like `body` tag